# meaning of multiple .col in single line with pug and bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, pug

I'm using bootstrap and pug/jade and I've been looking at some example code that uses multiple .col in a single line (e.g. .col-md-4.col-md-offset-4). I can't figure out what this does, particularly the difference between multiple .col in a single line (like above) or multiple lines (.col-md-4 and .col-md-offset-4 in different lines). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

.container-fluid
     .row
          .col-md-4.col-md-offset-4

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Offset classes**
Move columns to the right using .offset-md-* classes. These classes increase the left margin of a column by * columns. For example, .offset-md-4 moves .col-md-4 over four columns.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">.col-md-4 .offset-md-4</div>
</div>
```

Here you can see the difference:

[image: Screenshot of two Bootstrap columns spanning four columns each, separated by a four column gap.]

Refer to the [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. I was confused by the syntax of having .col-md-4.col-offset-md-4 (two .col in the same line) but I guess that translates to .col-md-4 .offset-md-4.